# Need to access documentation for Plutus.Contract.Oracle but not available in https://input-output-hk.github.io/plutus/master/

Tags: plutus, documentation

Playground is discontinued but the updated documentation seems to be lacking in components that I have been working with.

I did try to look up the other versions they have listed in their gh-pages repo here https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/tree/gh-pages but those pages also don't seem to have those

Any idea how I can access the old documentation I have tried the way back machine as well but it doesnt have those pages cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the Haddock documentation, it moved [here](https://input-output-hk.github.io/plutus-apps/main/) (for plutus-apss) and [there](https://input-output-hk.github.io/plutus/master/) (for plutus).

Some modules are still missing in the plutus-apps repo, we're working on it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).